# php: copy or cut file

Tags: php

i have in server big files (50mb) and i need this file move  to other folder.
But with function

> copy()

takes too many long.

how make this process faster?

Comment: Is this a windows server or a linux server? also, are you allowed to use system()?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `rename ()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

```
<?php
rename("/tmp/tmp_file.txt", "/home/user/login/docs/my_file.txt");
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If the other folder is on the same hardware, you can do a [rename](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)() instead.